# How to subract integer data using the other table with date condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to decrement the _remain_overall_quantity from `inventory` table  by using the feed_consumed in `consumption` table

[image]

In condition

if `$chickenAge` <= 8
 The decrement will occur in **CBC**

if `$chickenAge` > 8 && `$chickenAge` <= 20 
 The decrement will occur in **BSC**

if `$chickenAge` > 20
 The decrement will occur in **BFP**

This is my ConsumptionController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'date_input' => 'required|date',
        'feed_consumed' => 'required|numeric',
        ) );
            //declaring values
            $chickenAge = 0;
            $input= Carbon::parse($request->get('date_input'));
            $cycle = Cycle::where('date_of_loading','<=',$input)
            ->where('date_of_harvest','>=',$input)
            ->first();

        if ($cycle)   {
            $start = Carbon::parse($cycle->date_of_loading);
            $chickenAge = $start->diffInDays($input) ;
        }

        $inventory = Inventory::where('cycle_id','=',$cycle->id ?? 0)
            ->first();

        $consumption = Consumption::create([
            'date_input' => request('date_input'),
            'chicken_age' => $chickenAge,
            'feed_consumed' => request('feed_consumed'),
            'cycle_id'  => $cycle->id ?? 0,
            'user_id'  => Auth::id()
        ]);

        return $consumption;
}
```

I don't know where can i put the decrement and i don't know what will be the if condition statement. Can you help me?

Comment: do you want to decrement the rows in `inventory` table by 1 every time you hit the store method of this controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this code just before you `return` statement:

```
if ($chickenAge <= 8)
{
    DB::table('inventory')->where('id', 1)->decrement('remain_overall_quantity ', 1); // CBC
}
elseif ($chickenAge <= 20)
{
    DB::table('inventory')->where('id', 2)->decrement('remain_overall_quantity ', 1); // BSC
}
else
{
    DB::table('inventory')->where('id', 3)->decrement('remain_overall_quantity ', 1); // BFP
}
```

if you need to decrement by more than 1 then  change the "1" in `'remain_overall_quantity ', 1` part

some insight to increment/decrement in Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement